# Converting from Task<(string,object)> to Task<string>

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Is it possible to convert from `Task<(string,object)>` to `Task<string>`? I have a method that receive `Task<string>` as argument, but from another method returning type I am getting `Task<(string,object)>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.continuewith?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_ContinueWith__1_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__0____0__) converts a `Task<T>` to `Task<U>`, using the given `Func<Task<T>, U>`:

```
Task<(string, object)> tupleTask = MethodThatReturnsTupleTask();
Task<string> stringTask = tupleTask.ContinueWith(tuple => tuple.Result.Item1);
MethodThatAcceptsStringTask(stringTask);
```

Comment: [I don't think](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) that Stephen Cleary will like your approach. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias that’s what I get for thinking of tasks as functors! I ignored a lot of the details and jumped to conclusions.

Comment: Yeap, the `ContinueWith` method is too primitive, and too cumbersome to work with. Honestly it's not a well made mechanism. In case the `tupleTask` fails, the `stringTask` will contain a nested `AggregateException`, which will make the error handling a real mess.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use a lambda:

```
var task_with_obj = func();

Func<Task<string>> func_string = async () => (await task_with_obj).Item1;
var task = func_string();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [LINQ to Tasks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/tasks-monads-and-linq/):

```
Task<(string, object)> task1 = GetStuffAsync();
Task<string> task2 = task1.Select(value => value.Item1);
```

Here is the `Select` operator:

```
public static async Task<T2> Select<T1, T2>(this Task<T1> source, Func<T1, T2> selector)
{
    return selector(await source);
}
```

A complete Linq-to-Tasks "suite" can be found here: [LinqToTasks.cs](https://github.com/donatasm/ParallelExtensionsExtras/blob/master/src/Extensions/LinqToTasks.cs). It is part of the [ParallelExtensionsExtras](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ParallelExtensionsExtras/) package. Its implementation predates async/await, so it is based on the [primitive](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) method, with all that entails (poor exception behavior etc).